# How to build Kie session when using dsl and dslr files?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I am new at drools. I have executed rules from my drl file.
Here is my drl file.

```
rule "Person is 21"
salience 1
    when
        $person : Person(age>=21,car.equalsIgnoreCase("duster"))               
    then
        System.out.println($person.name);
end
```

here is my model file

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String car;




    public Person()
    {

    }

    public Person(String name, int age,String car)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.car=car;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }


    public String getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(String car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

}
```

Here is my rule runner method code that takes rules and facts as arguments and builds kie session and fires rules

```
 public void runRules(String[] rules, Object[] facts)
    {

        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieResources kieResources = kieServices.getResources();
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();

        for(String ruleFile : rules)
        {
            Resource resource = kieResources.newClassPathResource(ruleFile);

            // path has to start with src/main/resources
            // append it with the package from the rule
            kieFileSystem.write( resource);
        }

        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);

        kb.buildAll();

        if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Level.ERROR))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults().toString());
        }

        KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());

        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();

        for (Object fact : facts)
        {
            kSession.insert(fact);
        }

        kSession.fireAllRules();
    }
```

What changes should i do when I am using a dslr file(below is the dslr file)

```
rule "My First Rule"

    when
        Person is at least 21 and car is "duster"
    then
        Log : "hello world"

end
```

In eclipse the drl file generated from the dslr file is correct.
Below is the rule in the drl file generated by the dsl expander(which I could see in the drl viewer in eclipse for the above dslr)

```
rule "My First Rule"

    when
        i: Person(age > 21, car=="duster")
    then
        System.out.println("hello world");

end
```

I tried running the same rule from my drl file and it executed successfully

The problem I am facing is that I tried passing both DSL and DSLR files as arguments to the rule resource

```
Resource resource = kieResources.newClassPathResource("MyDslr.dslr","dslExample.dsl");
```

and I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Build Errors:
Error Messages:
Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=MyDslr.dslr, line=17, column=0
   text=[17] No mapping entries for expanding:         Person is at least 21 and
 car is "duster"]
Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=MyDslr.dslr, line=17, column=0
   text=[17] Unable to expand: Person is at least 21 and car is "duster"]
Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=MyDslr.dslr, line=19, column=0
   text=[19] No mapping entries for expanding:         Log : "hello world"]
Message [id=4, level=ERROR, path=MyDslr.dslr, line=19, column=0
   text=[19] Unable to expand:         Log : "hello world"]
Message [id=5, level=ERROR, path=MyDslr.dslr, line=17, column=0
   text=[ERR 102] Line 17:15 mismatched input 'is' in rule "My First Rule"]
---
Warning Messages:
---
Info Messages:

    at controller.RuleRunner.runRules(RuleRunner.java:43)
    at mainPackage.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Here is how my dsl file looks like in eclipse(and it is converting the dslr in drl and the converted rule gives no exception when is rul it directly from the drl file)
[image]

Please help me out here. And if there are examples of how to fire rules using kie api and dslr and dsl files then that will also help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call

```
... = kieResources.newClassPathResource("MyDslr.dslr","dslExample.dsl")
```

can't be correct - compare the Javadoc for this method: the second argumen should indicate an encoding.

This sequence of statements, however, works:

```
FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream( "simple/simple.dsl" );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.dsl",
           kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis1 ) );
FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream( "simple/simple.dslr" );
kfs.write( "src/main/resources/simple.dslr",
           kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource( fis2 ) );
KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
```

You should call your method `runRules(String[] rules, Object[] facts)` with an array of pathnames, DSL as well as DSLR.